# Tweeting two different elements with tweepy

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, tweepy

I'm trying to tweet two elements with tweepy like:

```
api.update_status(item, "-Oliver")
```

However when I tweet that, it only tweets "item" instead of "Item -Oliver" 
I tried combining it so

```
total = item, "-Oliver"
api.update_status(total)
```

But that tweet looks like: (u'Jake Gyllenhaal', '-Oliver') My code this far is:

```
#movie loving bot
import requests
import re
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as BS
import tweepy
from secrets import *

#create OAuthHandler instance
#Twitter requires all requests to use OAuth for authentification
auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(consumer_key, consumer_secret)

auth.set_access_token(access_token, access_secret)

#construct API instance
#entry point for operations performed with twitter 
api = tweepy.API(auth) #create an API object

calcAgain = True
while (calcAgain == True):
    movie = raw_input("What movie u want? If title more than 1 word seperate             with hyphen: ")
    crewType = raw_input("What crew person u want: ")

    link = "https://letterboxd.com/film/%s/" % (movie)
    #requesting page data 
    page = requests.get(link)
    #getting html content from page 
    soup = BS(page.content, 'html.parser')

    easyCrew = ['director', 'actor']

    if crewType in easyCrew:
        crews = soup.find('a', {'itemprop' : crewType})
        crew = crews.find('span', {'itemprop' : 'name'})
        for item in crew:
            total = item, "-Oliver"
            api.update_status(total)

    invalidAns2 = True #checks for valid input 
    while (invalidAns2) == True : #try again loop
        exit = raw_input("Anotha one? (y/n)")
        if exit == 'y' or exit == 'Y': #play again
            invalidAns2 = False  
        elif exit == 'n' or exit == 'N': #end program
            print "Thanks for playing, goodbye!"
            invalidAns2 = False 
            calcAgain = False
        else : 
            print "Please enter y for yes or n for no." #error statement
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`update_status()`](http://docs.tweepy.org/en/v3.5.0/api.html#API.update_status) expects a text (string) of a tweet as the first argument, *concatenate the strings*:

```
total = item + "-Oliver"
api.update_status(total)
```